# Redis read-write concurrency

Tags: redis, redis-cluster

I have a usecase where we need to bulk write into a redis cluster(few million records) that basically overwrite the existing records, will this affect the read operation during the window

Comment: What's your bulk write? Write multiple keys in a transaction, e.g. `MSET`? Or Write multiple keys with pipeline, i.e. these write operations are not atomic?

Answer (score 1):

As Redis is single-threaded  while a command is running, no other command can be executed. 
But being in memory this is very fast . If your concern is regarding data replication then Redis replicates the data across cluster ( to slaves) asynchronously. If you are reading from slaves this might have some lag.

Comment: But the read itself has a chance of being blocked? on a key level, if I'm asking the right question

Comment: In production environment I have preferred to use slaves for reads ( if application can live with probable replication lag) so that any impact is very minimal.

Comment: I saw this in an article, from which I understand that, we might end up with client connection errors during the high volume writes with persistence turned on..   "*Review your persistence requirements and Redis configuration. Does your app modify more keys when you get more traffic and do you need persistence? Consider AOF or rolling BGSAVE as an alternative to standard snapshotting. This may avoid connection/command execution timeouts and blocking Redis instances.*"

Comment: This is true because when snapshotting the process is forked and depending upon the kind of machine you have it introduces latency as it is CPU intensive. So this kind of delay is because of the choice of persistence we have made. Remember REDIS is mostly CPU bound. Check out the details on latency here https://redis.io/topics/latency

Comment: From my gut feel I think a sudden burst of large data inserts may impact the reads definitely ( even if little) if you are using snapshotting,  that's why using read slaves are generally better idea. A better way to understand the impact would be to write a benchmark against your cluster. Populate your cluster with keys , run the read client , check the response time distributions and throughput. Next perform your updates for a sustained time, run your read client and again measure the metrics.

Comment: How Radis will maintain data consistency, if master is being rewritten and slave is being read at same time?  e.g. Master being deducting 100 bucks out of 200, and slave is reading balance 200 for further deducting, this is just and example